# Color overlay on hover does not show up on just one element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend

my CSS class with pseudo

```
.fc-state-col:hover .fc-state-col::after
```

does not work everything else is fine

The following CSS classes with hover pseudo is working fine

```
.fc-state-col:hover .hover-show
.fc-state-col:hover .hover-moveUp
```

I have an image in a bootstrap .container-fluid with a color overlay. That container-fluid has 6 equal full height columns inside it.

Upon hover, the overlay on the image should disappear then a new image shows up. (this works no problem here)

A new overlay on the specific column where the mouse hovers will show up together with a paragraph and a button at the bottom of that column.

So only the specific column where the mouse hovers will have a color overlay. the remaining 5 columns have no color overlay. (this does not work)

The paragraph and button show up upon hover but the color overlay on the columns does not. I hope someone can spot my error or what I am missing thank you so much in advance

```css
:root {
    --blue-opaque: hsl(207, 59%, 33%, .85);
    --red-opaque: hsl(353,87%,25%, .85);
    --yellow: #e9ba2d;
    --fc-overlay: rgba(107, 17, 28, .75);
    --white-vl: rgba(255, 255, 255, .85);
}
#fc-red-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--red-opaque);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vw;
  top: 4%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 600ms ease;
}

#fc:hover #fc-red-overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
}

.fc-state-col {
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

#fc-red-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--red-opaque);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vw;
  top: 4%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 600ms ease;
}

#fc:hover #fc-red-overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -10;
}

.fc-state-col {
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.fc-state-col::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--red-opaque);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in;
}

.fc-state-col:hover .fc-state-col::after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.hover-show {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.fc-state-col:hover .hover-show {
  opacity: .9;
}

.hover-moveUp {
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in;
}

.fc-state-col:hover .hover-moveUp {
  position: relative;
  top: -17rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row fc-states-row align-items-end">
  <div class="col-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end fc-state-col">
    <div class="vl hover-moveUp"></div>

    <h3 class="text-white text-center text-uppercase align-self-center hover-moveUp">Location 1</h3>
    
    <p class="text-white text-center pt-3 hover-show">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam eligendi quas corporis excepturi officia, beatae ad dolorem aperiam. Reprehenderit suscipit eius iusto officiis ad Necessitatibus numquam laboriosam saepe, atque fugit, magni neque dolores
      nemo nobis, architecto quaerat corrupti.</p>
      
    <button class="btn btn-warning border-0 text-white align-self-center hover-show">VIEW DETAILS</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end fc-state-col">
    <div class="vl hover-moveUp"></div>

    <h3 class="text-white text-center text-uppercase align-self-center hover-moveUp">Location 1</h3>
    
    <p class="text-white text-center pt-3 hover-show">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam eligendi quas corporis excepturi officia, beatae ad dolorem aperiam. Reprehenderit suscipit eius iusto officiis ad Necessitatibus numquam laboriosam saepe, atque fugit, magni neque dolores
      nemo nobis, architecto quaerat corrupti.</p>
      
    <button class="btn btn-warning border-0 text-white align-self-center hover-show">VIEW DETAILS</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="fc-red-overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question and not just announce your state of being.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Please add your variables to the demo above (or substitute values) so we can see the problem.

Comment: I have made some edits to my title and description thank you

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of thinking and not thinking about it, I was able to solve this problem.

I added a new empty div at the bottom of each column

```
<div class="col-2 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end fc-state-col">
  <div class="vl hover-moveUp"></div>
  <h3 class="text-white text-center text-uppercase align-self-center hover-moveUp ">LOCATION</h3>
  <p class="text-white text-center pt-3 hover-show">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam eligendi quas corporis excepturi officia, beatae ad dolorem aperiam. Reprehenderit suscipit eius iusto officiis ad Necessitatibus numquam laboriosam saepe, atque fugit, magni neque dolores nemo nobis, architecto quaerat corrupti.</p>
  <button class="btn btn-warning border-0 text-white align-self-center hover-show">VIEW DETAILS</button>
  <div class="fc-state-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

then I changed the CSS as follows:

```
.fc-state-overlay::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;        
    background-color: var(--red-opaque);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: transform 350ms ease-in;
}

.fc-state-col:hover .fc-state-overlay::after {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  
}
```

instead of:

```
.fc-state-col::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--red-opaque);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in;
}

.fc-state-col:hover .fc-state-col::after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

Maybe I cannot use the same element as the hover trigger and also the same element with the ::after pseudo content which in this case is the color overlay.

So I created an empty div with the hover on overlay  effect